# ga:dfpRevenue is Restricted

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-dfp

I am trying to fetch Double Click for Publishers data from my Google Analytics account, but the dfp metrics are not possivble to fetch via the reporting api.

Am I right that I need to have GA360 for this?

That's the error message:

> Restricted metric(s): ga:dfpRevenue can only be queried under certain conditions. For details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.

Can I fetch this data via the google DFP API?

Comment: I just tested it with a 360 account and it dosent work for me either.   I will email Google see what they have to say.

Comment: Okay sounds great. I wait for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Set up the DoubleClick for Publishers reporting integration](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6183304?hl=en)

> Preflight checklist To see DFP reports in GA the following criteria
>   must be met:
>
> 1. You have a Google Analytics 360 account.
> 2. The majority of tags on your site are Google Publisher Tags (GPT).
> 3. Select a user who will be an administrator of both DFP and GA Premium.

This will only work with a 360 account which has been set up to use GPT

Comment: You can probably use the DFP api if you have access to that I don't so cant test it for you.   Try it and ask another question if you have any problems https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/start